# que + conjuntivo

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Foi-me dito que frases como a seguinte estão erradas:

> fico/fiquei feliz que tenham/tivessem vindo

No entanto, se por um lado ninguém parece capaz de explicar porquê, por outro nunca aparecem construções semelhantes como exemplos de uso do conjuntivo, seja na Internet ou na *gramática do Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra*. A minha dúvida é se estão erradas e qual a razão?

Answer (score 3):

As tuas frases estão corretas. Temos um exemplo com a mesma estrutura na  *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, tomo II, p. 1889; formatação minha):

> E houve muita gente que ficou e ele provavelmente **ficou contente que tivessem ficado**.

O trecho a negrito é perfeitamente paralelo às tuas frases:

> Fiquei [feliz *que tivessem vindo*]
> Fico [feliz *que tenham vindo*]

Aplicando a análise da *Gramática do Português* (p. 1875-7) à última frase, por exemplo,
o que nós temos é um sintagma adjetival — *feliz que tenham vindo* — constituído por um  núcleo, *feliz*,  e pelo seu complemento: a oração completiva oracional finita *que tenham vindo*; diz-se completiva porque completa o sentido de *feliz*; não se afirma que a pessoa está feliz em geral; simplesmente que ela está feliz com a vinda deles.

Há nestas frases duas coisas corretas mas que poderão gerar estranheza, e que vale por isso a pena esclarecer.

### Possível preposição suprimida em *feliz (?) que tenham vindo*

Os complementos de adjetivos são normalmente introduzidos por uma preposição. A *Gramática do Português* (p. 1874) explica que a preposição é obrigatória quando o complemento é uma expressão nominal (como *feijoada*) ou uma oração infinitiva (*comer uma feijoada*):

> Estamos todos [desejosos **de** *feijoada*]
> Estamos todos [desejosos **de** *comer uma feijoada*]

Mas a preposição é frequentemente opcional quando o complemento é uma oração finita. Exemplos da *Gramática* (p. 1873 e 1877) em que a preposição entre parênteses é opcional:

> Estamos todos [desejosos (de) *que esta semana passe depressa*]
> Eles estão [ansiosos (por) *que ela chegue*]

Então põe-se a questão: qual é a preposição opcional suprimida nas nossas frases? E aqui há uma coisa curiosa. Normalmente um adjetivo usa a mesma preposição com qualquer tipo de complemento, como se vê acima no caso de *desejoso*, em que a preposição é sempre *de*. Mas com os adjetivos *feliz, contente* e *satisfeito*, a preposição varia com o tipo de complemento:

- com complementos nominais, preferem a preposição *com* (*feliz com a chegada do filho*);
- com orações infinitivas, preferem *por* (*feliz por o filho ter chegado*; no passado também se encontra *de o filho ter chegado*);
- e com orações finitas, quando usa preposição, é *de*, como neste exemplo do dicionário de Moraes Silva (1890)  [“contente de que [a vontade de Deus] se faça”](https://books.google.pt/books?id=l804AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA513&dq=%22resignado%20contente%20de%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjehde83oXuAhVP3IUKHehmAVEQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22resignado%20contente%20de%20que%22&f=false) ou neste mais recente do Pe. Omar (2012), [“fico feliz de que sejamos […]”](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9QEAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&dq=%22feliz%20de%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdl6Dr-ujtAhUGwlkKHRU3CIAQ6AEwE3oECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22feliz%20de%22&f=false). No entanto de longe o mais comum, com orações finitas, é não usar preposição nenhuma. Andei a vasculhar o Google Books, e esta preferência parece vir pelo menos já do século XV, como nestes exemplos de Fernão Lopes (1385 – 1460), [“contente que ele fosse um deles”](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BpwvAQAAMAAJ&q=%22era%20contente%20que%20elle%20fosse%22&dq=%22era%20contente%20que%20elle%20fosse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA3ouOkuftAhXi0eAKHSOfC2gQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg) e do Padre António Vieira (1608 – 97) [“contente que […] se queime”](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RR5FAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22contente%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj55_yJnOftAhXHDWMBHZa3DF04FBDoATAFegQIDBAC#v=onepage&q=%22contente%20que%22&f=false).

### Uso do conjuntivo/subjuntivo

Nas tuas frases, o verbo do complemento oracional finito está no conjuntivo (termo preferido em Portugal) ou subjuntivo (preferido no Brasil): *que tenham vindo* (pretérito perfeito), *que tivessem vindo* (pretérito mais-que-perfeito). No entanto referem um evento real: a frase, por exemplo, *fiquei feliz que tivessem vido* implica que eles realmente vieram. Isto poderá causar uma certa estranheza, porque conjuntivo está normalmente associado ao incerto, potencial, hipotético.

Mas este uso do conjuntivo está correto. Explica a *Gramática do Português* (p. 1841-2) que nos complementos oracionais finitos o indicativo só se usa para transmitir uma atitude de conhecimento (*sei que ele chegou*, *estou certo (de) que ele chegou*). Para outras atitudes usa-se o conjuntivo. Nomeadamente, e passo a citar:

> De uma forma geral, selecionam o conjuntivo no verbo da oração subordinada:
> […]
> (iii) Os predicadores que expressam uma atitude de avaliação perante um dado estado de coisas, como os verbos *detestar, gostar* (*de*), *lamentar, suportar* e *tolerar*, entre outros; lexias verbais *achar bem*/*mal*, o nome *pena*, os adjetivos *agradável, bom, insuportável, lamentável* e *triste*, entre muitos outros, como se ilustra a seguir:
>
> (82)   a. Lamento/Detesto [que o João *tenha* decidido sair do país].
>           b. É triste [que eles se *comportem* dessa forma].
>
> Apesar de, tipicamente, o modo conjuntivo estar associado ao domínio do incerto ou do hipotético, não existe uma relação direta entre conjuntivo e “não realidade”. Com efeito, os predicadores avaliativos, como *lamentar* ou *triste*, permitem inferir a verdade da proposição expressa no complemento; porém não selecionam o indicativo (cf. *eu lamento que a Maria tenha visto o filme*, frase na qual o uso do verbo *lamentar* como predicador da oração principal permite inferir a verdade da proposição ‘a Maria viu o filme’; cf. 36.4). Este facto deve-se ao tipo de modalidade envolvida, que não é epistémica e sim avaliativa.

Também em *fico feliz que tenham vindo*, a atitude não é epistémica mas sim avaliativa; é o mesmo tipo de atitude que em *gostei que tivessem vindo*, por exemplo, em que *gostar* (*de*), como diz a *Gramática*, exige o conjuntivo no complemento oracional.

Answer (score 1):

Em geral essas frases *não* estão erradas. Por exemplo, a frase

> Fico feliz que tenham vindo.

está perfeitamente correta. "Tenham" (por si só) é uma conjugação de "ter" no presente do subjuntivo (também chamado de *conjuntivo*) simples, e acompanha a conjunção "que". Quando combinado com o particípio do verbo "vir" ("vindo"), temos o presente do subjuntivo composto do verbo "vir": "tenham vindo".

Exemplos do presente do subjuntivo composto podem ser encontrados [nesta página](https://www.todamateria.com.br/modo-subjuntivo/) para a terceira pessoa do singular ("ele") e a primeira do plural ("nós"):

> Penso que ele já tenha saído.
>
> É possível que nós tenhamos guardado esse documento.

A frase "Fiquei feliz que tivessem vindo" parece-me sintaticamente correta (uma conjugação do pretérito mais-que-perfeito do subjuntivo do verbo "vir"), mas semanticamente incorreta, pois "que tivessem vindo" conota uma possibilidade que poderia ter se realizado porém não aconteceu, o que não é bem acomponhado por "fiquei", que conota algo que realmente se passou. Duas alternativas parecidas mas com sentido diferente são corretas:

> Ficaria feliz se tivessem vindo

O exemplo acima significa que, se a possibilidade de eles virem tivesse se realizado, então eu ou alguém teria ficado feliz.

Note que aqui usei o "se" ao invés do "que", que parece mais natural por tratar-se de uma situação hipotética. Não tenho certeza se "Ficaria feliz que tivessem vindo" está correta ou não, mas aos meus ouvidos não soa natural.

> Fiquei feliz que tenham vindo

Já esse exemplo é parecido com o exemplo inicial "Fico feliz que tenham vindo", porém expressa essa felicidade num momento passado ao invés do presente.

Pode-se encontrar exemplos da conjugação destes tempos na mesma página citada acima.

Comment: Tens aqui vários equívocos. Nos exemplos da pergunta, não tens o presente e “o pretérito”: tens o  pretérito perfeito (tenham vindo) e o pretérito mais-que-perfeito (tivessem vindo) do verbo *vir*. Simplesmente *tivessem* é o pretérito imperfeito, e pode perfeitamente vir acompanhado de *que*: “pediu-lhes que tivessem coragem”; a página que indicaste é muito básica, mas mesmo assim encontras lá “mesmo **que comesse**”. >>

Comment: >> Mas o facto de um ou outro tempo do subjuntivo poder vir acompanhado de *que*, não quer dizer que uma construção em particular esteja certa ou errada. Eu inclino-me a pensar que não há erro nenhum em qualquer das frases (feliz que tenham/tivessem vindo), mas não encontrei na tal página nenhuma construção do mesmo tipo (apesar de tu dizeres que há).

Comment: @Jacinto: Eu procurei ignorar a distinção subjuntivo simples/composto (focando-me na conjugação do auxiliar apenas no caso do composto) mas de fato pode parecer impreciso, por isso reformulei a resposta para ressaltar esta distinção.

Quanto a usar o pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo com "que", de fato é possível ao contrário do que eu tinha dito, por isso corrigi. De qualquer maneira parece-se estranho dizer "Ficaria feliz que tivessem vindo", mas não sei dizer se é gramaticalmente incorreto.

Comment: Quanto a exemplos, eu me referia a exemplos das conjugações, não a exemplos de "se" ou "que" com o subjuntivo composto, que a referida página parece realmente não incluir.

Comment: Eu também não digo "ficaria feliz que tivessem vindo"; digo "teria ficado feliz se tivessem vindo" / "ficaria feliz se viessem"; mas isto é irrelevante para a questão. Na questão é: vocês vieram e eu fico feliz com isso → "fico feliz que tenham vindo"; há dois anos vocês vieram e eu fiquei feliz → "fiquei feliz que tivessem vindo". A tua sugestão "fiquei feliz que tenham vindo" soa-me muito estranho; Encontrei "ficou contente que tivessem ficado" numa gramática. Vê na minha resposta.

Comment: Quanto a soar estranho, pode ser uma questão de diferença entre Brasil e Portugal. "Fico feliz que tenham vindo" soa extremamente natural para mim e acho que para muitos brasileiros também. Houve uma conversa parecida no seguinte e parece que ali também surgiu a questão Brasil/Portugal:
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/que-tivessem-tenham-vindo.3773736/

Comment: Em particular, um outro brasileiro comenta: ""Fico feliz que tivessem vindo" não me parece que se use no Brasil. A mim me soa estranhíssimo. Diríamos "fico feliz que tenham vindo", para usarmos o imperfeito do subjuntivo teríamos de dizer "teria ficado feliz feliz se tivessem vindo". "

Comment: Usa-se, usa-se. Isto é tudo de autores brasileiros: [Ficaram felizes que Bernardo tivesse encontrado alguém](https://books.google.pt/books?id=i0aaq8h_lZgC&pg=PA21&dq=%22ficaram+felizes+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHvaOF4JnuAhUDmRoKHcFGAxQQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ficaram%20felizes%20que%22&f=false); [fiquei contente que você tivesse lembrado de mim](https://books.google.pt/books?id=R548AAAAYAAJ&q=%22fiquei+contente+que%22&dq=%22fiquei+contente+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2iOKF8JPuAhU2D2MBHcE4CZAQ6AEwA3oECAMQAg).

Comment: E este do antigo presidente Juscelino Kubitscheck: [fiquei satisfeito que assim houvesse acontecido](https://books.google.pt/books?id=k8wrAAAAYAAJ&q=%22fiquei+satisfeito+que%22&dq=%22fiquei+satisfeito+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6rtbp8pPuAhXRYcAKHd3kBMMQ6AEwBXoECAoQAg); Em Portugal estas construções são todas muito raras; ao ponto de eu ter estranhado isto ao princípio. A maneira comum de exprimir esta ideia aqui é "fico/fiquei feliz por terem vindo". O que se diz por aqui é coisas do tipo, "foi pena/lamento que ele não tivesse vindo antes", que na verdade é o mesmo complemento.

Comment: Interessante. Claramente você sabe mais do que eu, mas o que vejo é o seguinte: note que nos seus exemplos o verbo "ficar" está no pretérito, e "fiquei feliz" denota uma felicidade referente um fato num passado ainda mais remoto, e por isso nesse caso cabe o pretérito-mais-que-perfeito "tivesse vindo", que denota um passado anterior a um fato passado. Se "ficar feliz" está no presente e esa felicidade se refere a um fato passado, então "vir" é conjugado no pretérito perfeito "tenha vindo": "fico feliz que tenha vindo".

Comment: Perfeitamente de acordo: "fico feliz que tenham vido; fiquei feliz que tivessem vindo". Creio que houve um mal-entendido. Deves ter lido mal um comentário meu anterior (6 acima, Jan 10 at 19:15). Repetindo e elaborando: eu estranhei a sugestão na tua reposta, "fiquei feliz que tenham vindo", precisamente porque eu entendo a vinda como anterior ao "fiquei", que já está no pretérito. Mas vi entretanto, que essa construção é frequente na literatura brasileira; também com o indicativo, tipo "fico feliz que vieram".