# Diz-se "guloso de" ou "guloso por"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulário

Em português formal, diz-se corretamente "guloso de (algo)" ou "guloso por (algo)"? Ou ambas as formas estão corretas?

Trata-se da tradução de uma frase que constitui a descrição do bombardeio de Orléans em 1940, tal qual pensada por Louis-Ferdinand Céline em "Guignol's Band I" (1944): "... serpents sifflants accolés de crapauds, bouffis, de lèpre, juteux, jaunes à vernis, **suçons goulus de salamandres**, vampires repoussants au corps des damnés..." (CÉLINE, 1951, p. 23).

Comment: Podes fornecer uma frase? Isso melhoraria a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão. Trata-se de uma tradução. A frase em francês é: "goulus de salamandres". Em português seria "gulosos de/por salamandras" ?

Comment: Ótimo você já ter colocado a frase, AFM, seria possível também mencionar a fonte ou o contexto? Pergunto porque os dicionários indicam que "goulus" também poderia ser "gananciosos".

Comment: Trata-se da descrição do bombardeio de Orléans em 1940, feita por Louis-Ferdinand Céline em "Guignol's Band I" (1944): "... serpents sifflants accolés de crapauds, bouffis, de lèpre, juteux, jaunes à vernis, suçons goulus de salamandres, vampires repoussants au corps des damnés..." (CÉLINE, 1951, p. 23).

Comment: Assumindo que dizes, por certo, “guloso”, então, garanto que podes usar “de” (https://aulete.com.br/guloso, https://aulete.com.br/gula e exemplos em https://dicionario.priberam.org/guloso), como em "ela é gulosa de falar mal dos outros". Eu acho que "por" pode ser usado, mas me parece haver alguma diferença entre "ela é gulosa de falar mal dos outros" e "ela é guloso por falar mal dos outros", porém, não sei qual é; uma diferença sutil.

Comment: @Schilive, Nos links encontro apenas um exemplo (dentro os do Priberam - de um blog do Sapo) com uma preposição associada a "guloso" - não me parece que baste para "garantir" que seu uso é correto embora concorde que pareça ser.

Comment: @stafusa, no Aulete, em "Verbete Original", há os dois exemplos.

Comment: @Schilive Ah, ok, não tinha reparado nessa 'aba'. Mesmo nela só encontro um exemplo ("gulosos de certa lagarta"), mas claro que já justifica a menção.

Comment: @stafusa, a outra é um talvez-mas-provavelmente-porém-incerto-exemplo: "Mas a gula... de livros de viagem é também considerável".

Comment: O francês é bem complicado. En francês, pode-se dizer: ser guloso de [algo]. Só que como que um chupão pode ser guloso de salamanda? Pessoalmente, para mim, quer dizer: salamandras[ que são] gulosas DE chupões. Isso sim.

Comment: em português, pode-se ser gulosa/o para algo. Sou gulosa para docês: https://aboboramenina-cristina.blogspot.com/2017/09/cuca-alema-de-uva.html salamandras gulosas **para** chupões.

Comment: O autor faz um inversão: Ele fala que os chupões são gulosos para as salamandras, o que é impossível. Mas ele é bem shato com esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: @Lambie Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Guloso" raramente recebe complemento, pelo menos hoje em dia<sup>1</sup> e especialmente em pt-BR.

Sua regência não é especificada em nenhum dos dicionários que chequei e não consta em nenhuma lista de regências nominais que pude encontrar.

Também o [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/), excetuando os *hits* irrelevantes, i.e., que não têm relação com a regência de "guloso" (como, e.g., "O cão é guloso por natureza" e "O kit de manicure mais guloso de sempre"), retorna um só resultado para "guloso por" ("o Estado atual guloso por regulamentações") e dois ou três para "guloso de" (ex.: "guloso de pitéu feminino"). Schilive menciona mais um exemplo, de um blog, "um guloso de iguarias doces" e buscadores retornam uns poucos mais com "por", particularmente de descrições de vídeos pornográficos — mas o conjunto de exemplos permanece de qualidade duvidosa, reduzido demais e, portanto, inconclusivo.

Assim, eu evitaria a construção "guloso + [complemento]", mas, se utilizada, provavelmente qualquer das preposições seria aceitável, embora, por analogia com "fome", "de" [talvez seja preferível](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-regencia-de-fome/33436) a "por"<sup>1</sup>.

Com relação a frase específica da pergunta (sem saber francês, mas consultando dicionários e tradutores automáticos), imagino que talvez *goulu* possa ter na frase um sentido melhor capturado por uma palavra como "ávido" (+ "de" ou "por" [[1]](https://www.aulete.com.br/%C3%A1vido), [[2]](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/regencia-alguns-nomes.htm)), e me pergunto se não seria possível que a frase "*suçons goulus de salamandres*" significa na verdade algo como "sugadas/chupadas gulosas/ávidas de salamandras", ou seja, se o "de salamandres" não poderia se referir aos "suçons" e não a "goulus". Mas claro que não passa de especulação de pouco fundamento.

<sup>1</sup> Como o Jacinto aponta nos comentários, o Google Books retorna vários livros com "guloso por", especialmente na fala informal ou textos mais antigos e também em pt-PT.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta. Gosto da sua interpretação da frase. Esclarece finalmente, para mim, a relação entre "suçon" e "salamandre". Essa parte do texto me era especialmente penosa a compreender.

Comment: @AFM O prazer é meu. Se me permite sugerir, penso que incluir o teu comentário com a frase completa e fonte na própria pergunta (comentários podem ser apagados no futuro) seria uma boa ideia.

Comment: "Ávido" foi a primeira palavra que me ocorreu.

Comment: @ovide e sô moderador (parabéns), *guloso por* é comum em Portugal, e procurando diretamente no Google Books rapidamente encontrei mais de 20 resultados: guloso por doces, sorvete, saltões e gafanhotos, dinheiro, bytes; guloso por consumá-la, saber, me ouvir...  Também encontro na imprensa brasileira. *Guloso de* não se ouve por cá, mas encontra-se também no Google Books. Talvez tenha sido mais comum no passado: há exemplos do uso no passado da preposição *de* onde hoje só se usaria *por*: >>

Comment: >> "obrigado **do** grande festejo com que os Judeos o receberaõ" (1760); "contente **de** ver que a dama o manda" (Camões). Concordo com a interpretação do Stafusa: as salamandas fizeram chupões gulosos (chuparam com gula), não são os chupões que são gulosos por salamandras.

Comment: Obrigado, @Jacinto e obrigado pela correção, já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @Jacinto, pelo menos no Brasil, se usa "contente de", como "estou contente de te ver sorrindo". Em Portugal não se usa?

Comment: @Schilive, com o mesmo sujeito, "contente de [eu] te ver", não me soa estranho; mas mudando o sujeito, o que estou habituado a ouvir é *por*: "fico muito contente por [vocês] terem vindo"; o mesmo com *satisfeito, feliz, triste*.

Comment: @Schilive, olha que eu não sei se isto é regra; é apenas baseado no que me soa bem, que é baseado no que eu estou habituado a ouvir e ler. No Brasil pode ser diferente. No passado era certamente diferente. No exemplo do Camões que eu dei, na verdade o sujeito não muda, e o *de* soa-me estranho; talvez por o complemento ser longo. Mas há vários exemplos do passado com *de* e o sujeito a mudar: "pouco contente **de** em Portugal não lhe quererem dar o tratamento" (Pe. António Vieira); "estava contente **de** [os negócios] se acabarem tanto em paz" (João de Barros). Eu aqui usaria *por*.

Comment: @Jacinto, pelo menos para mim, "por" dá uma sensação de causa; "eu estou contente por vê-lo", vê-lo causou/causa eu estar contente; enquanto "de" me dá uma sensação de qualidade, de característica, então, "estou contente de vê-lo" diria que estou contente para com vê-lo, mas eu posso estar triste nesse dia, porque o meu gato morreu.  Então, o filho voltando para a casa dos pais por ter perdido o emprego, a mãe talvez esteja feliz por ele estar em casa, mas ela está triste de ele estar em casa. Esta é a diferença da qual falei nos comentários da resposta.

Comment: @Schilive, também pensei isso: "contente por" estou contente em absoluto, e *por* introduz a causa; "estou contente de [algo acontecer]", 'gosto que [esse algo acontença]'. Há uma construção antiga, "**ser** contente que [algo aconteça]", que significa 'aprovar que [algo aconteça]'; descobri isso quando andei a ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8322/que-conjuntivo). Agora se as pessoas escolhem entre *de* e *por* dessa maneira é que eu duvido. Em Portugal, uma pessoa diz "fico muito contente por terem vindo" mesmo no funeral dum filho.